# How do I fix a fractional exponent in Libertinus Math?

Tags: libertinus

I am very fond of Libertine, and was excited about better finished math display in Libertinus. But many math details are quite ugly when I set them in Libertinus. For example when I use a fraction in the exponent. Here is Libertinus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}

The curvature is defined as
\begin{equation}
\kappa_0 = \frac{h_{0,xx}}{\left( 1+h_{0,x}^2 \right)^\frac{3}{2}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result with Libertinus]

And here is the same in good old libertine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

The curvature is defined as
\begin{equation}
\kappa_0 = \frac{h_{0,xx}}{\left( 1+h_{0,x}^2 \right)^\frac{3}{2}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Libertine wins.
Am I doing anything wrong in the Libertinus code?
Thanks!

Comment: Bad, I agree. But `^{3/2}` is much better anyway. Without `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @egreg: I agree for this example. But it's not always an option.
From more looking around, I guess my best bet would be to define a custom \myfrac command...